# How to hide silly warnings in Poedit

Tags: warnings, punctuation, poedit

I'm translating English to Japanese in Poedit, and I'm getting warnings like this:

[image]

That ***is*** the Japanese character for a period/full-stop! I would like to either: teach Poedit what is perfectly valid punctuation (preferred, so that other warnings still appear), or disable these warnings altogether (plan B). Does anyone know how?

The only settings in Preferences that I thought might be applicable was "Check Spelling", but disabling that did nothing.

I recently upgraded to Poedit 2, and I don't remember seeing those warnings before, so perhaps it is a new "feature".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a new feature, and yes, it's not entirely perfect yet. As you may or may not be aware, bugs happen, and the traditional process of reporting them to the developer usually works quite well — considerably better, I dare say, than spewing snark at random Internet places.

Thanks for bringing this to my attention, will be fixed in 2.0.3. If you encounter more issues than this, please report them directly.

Comment: I didn't know I was being snarky - I thought I just didn't understand how to control the new behavior (I was imagining a "dictionary" I could add to or something). It didn't occur to me that it might be an actual bug. Before choosing to post here, I googled "poedit forum" and saw a Google Group, but it is not at all active (most recent post six months ago), so I came here. Now I see that you offer an email address even for free users - that is unusually generous! :-)

Comment: @OsakaWebbie I think putting "feature" in quotes qualifies as snark :) Generally speaking, any behavior that is stupid (as Poedit is being here) is arguably a bug.

Comment: For me also the warnings put headache instead of helping me. I use for ex. string like "{a} is not {b}" for parameters, and always get warnings that the sentense should be end with something. Is bad, that there is no way to turn of this warning thing.

Comment: Apparently this isn't fixed yet in 2.0.4. At least there should be an option to turn this 'feature' off.

Comment: @Allan Sun The above issue is, of course, fixed in 2.0.4. It only you would read the entirety of my reply...

Comment: @VáclavSlavík I am not sure what you mean by fixed in 2.0.4. I can still see it prompting **The translation should end with "."** when I have "." in the source code and "。" (Chinese full-stop) in the translation.

Comment: @AllanSun Either you don't have 2.0.4 or mis-declare language or get some other issue. It's kinda impossible for me to tell exactly because you never actually reported any problem  through normal support channels (see above), not to mention providing an example file. Surely as a developer, you do understand the importance of doing that, don't you? As I said before: if you encounter bogus warnings, do report them, with files, to help@poedit.net — that's the one thing that actually helps.